# return queue<vector> using a function in c++

Tags: c++, function, vector, queue

```
//16 lines
0000 0000
0001 1000
0010 0001
0011 1100
0100 0010
0101 0101
0110 1001
0111 1110
1000 0100
1001 0110
1010 1010
1011 0111
1100 0011
1101 1011
1110 1101
1111 1111
```

I created two vectors

`std::vector<std::bitset<4> > a` for 1st column

`std::vector<std::bitset<4> > b` for 2nd column

I want to form cycles using these vectors

example:

```
a[0] == b[0] --> display it
a[1] != b[1] --> 
//queue function which returns queue
push a[1],b[1] into queue --> check the value of b[1] in `vector a`return the position of b[1] in     a --> push value in b at position return -- > repeat it until queue.back() == queue.front() -- return    the entire queue
//end of queue

a[0] == b[0] -- > display it
a[1] != b[1] --> 
q1 <- a[1] , q1 <- b1 --> q1 = {a[1],b[1],....}
// function begin
then check value of b[1] in `a` and return the position `8` --> q1<-b[8] --> q1{a[1],b[1],b[8],...}      
then check value of b[8] in `a and return the position `4` --> q1<-b[4] -->    q1(a[1],b[1],b[8],b[4],.}
repeat it until last value of b[position] == q1.front(); 
return the entire queue q1--> {a[1],b[1],b[8],b[4],b[2]}
```

// function end

I want to use a function which returns the entire queue after all the operations are performed.Is it possible to return queue of vector values. If so can any one give me an example on how to code it with the above given example

```
if(a.at(0) == b.at(0))
{
   std:: cout << "a==b";
}
else
{
   //queue function starts here       
   //do some operations
   //return the queue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using C++ 11:

```
std::vector<std::bitset<4>> getVector() {
    std::vector<std::bitset<4>> result;

    result.push_back( ... );

    return result;
}
```

or using references in C++ 03:

```
void getVector(std::vector<std::bitset<4> >& result) {
    result.push_back( ... );
}
```